# ReactJS Meteor Pagination

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am creating application in Meteor using ReactJS for the UI.  I ran into a problem.  I am trying to read from a meteor collection and populate a grid with some data, this I have managed to achieve, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to do infinite scroll/pagination.

I stumbled across the  [paginate-subscriptions](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/paginated-subscription) meteor package, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Here is my code:

```
Container = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData() {
    var handle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('my-coll', 10);
    return {
      items: MyCollection.find({}).fetch()
    },

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {this.data.items.map(item => {
             <p>{item}</p>
          }}
        </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Instead of rendering 10 items, it will render all the items in the collection, which is not what I want.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> check **Kurounin** subscribe based pagination package. It works properly and no issues. Data tables also used. Check this [link](https://atmospherejs.com/kurounin/pagination)

Comment: @rony are there any issues with this pagination

Comment: I'm just moderator of this answer. I didn't down-voted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Griddle` Component for Grid it's good and provide all the functionality like Search sorting filter etc.
[Griddle](http://dynamictyped.github.io/Griddle/)

Comment: Can Griddle filter a grid of items, rather than a table?